# Ionic 2 deeplinking route from notifications

Tags: ionic2

I successfully implemented deeplinking when URL is called from the outside of the app (i.e. myapp://firstpage/1).

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    Deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.nav, {
      '/test': LoginPage,
    })
  });
}
```

When I receive notification from the server I get route assessment/1. How can I reroute after clicking on it using deepinking so I can use `'assessment/:assessmentId': assessmentDetailPage`.

There is always an option to do if or switch statement, but I am trying to avoid it since I'd also like to use defaultHistory.

I am open to other suggestions.